# Why doesn't Web API debugger hit?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rest

I have a new asp.net web api app in VS.NET 2013. I run the app in VS.NET. When I enter in this url:

```
http://localhost:8999/api/values
```

I get a popup in IE asking me to open a file. In Chrome, I get

> authorization has been denied for this request

I have break points set in the ValuesController. Any idea why the breakpoints aren't getting hit and why this doesn't work in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ValuesController** created by Web API Default Template has **Authorize** filter.

In order to see the JSON response, you want to either comment out or remove `[Authorize]`.

```
// [Authorize] <=== Either comment out or remove it.
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**FYI:** There are few tools to test Web Service instead of using browser. I personally like Fiddler and PostMan (Chrome plugin).

[image]